# Jquery submit specific input with enter key

Tags: jquery, key, submit, enter

is it posible avoid submit with enter key(13) in all input except only input???

```
$('#ruc').keypress(function(event){
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if(keycode == '13'){
    if ($('#ruc').val().length==11){
        //alert('ingreso DNI');
        mostrarDatosRUC($('#ruc').val());
      } else {
        alertify.error("El RUC debe tener 11 dígitos")
      }
    }
  });

});

$('form input'). keydown(function (e) {
  if (e. keyCode == 13) {
    e. preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

With this, $('#ruc').keypress(function(event) not working.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It works if you adjust your second function to

```
 $('form input:not(#ruc)'). keydown(function (e) {
    if (e. keyCode == 13) {
       e. preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: @Betto Glat that I was able to help :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.